# WPF MVVM Lights - Same user control with different parameter

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, mvvm-light

I have a WPF application using MVVM Light.
One MainView (+ *MainViewModel*) and One User Control (+ *UCViewModel*). 
The application will have a Tab control with 2 Tab Items.
Each tab will have a user control (same user control).
**User Control job:** Load the contents of the file, display the contents (and allow user to export it out to other format).
When application launch, I will read a config file and will pass the file location (from config file) to each user control (Eg: File1Path, File2Path).
I can use MVVM Light `Messenger.Default.Send` to do this job (From *MainViewModel* to *UCViewModel*). 

**My issue is**: How can I differentiate which User Control will get which file path? 
 
I use `SimpleIoc.Default.Register` in `ViewModelLocator` to register my *MainViewModel* and *UCViewModel*.
At the time of registration, I do not have the data from Config file yet so I cannot pass it to UCViewModel.

Any comment/solution for my issue?

Comment: Create a new Message where you set an id. Id=1 will be a file for view1, Id=2 will be a file for id=2. Or usethe existin message and send $"{filepath}, {id}"

Comment: @Marco, thanks for your suggestion. I also think of this way. But my UserControl ViewModel is only one but UserControl appears in two places. If I send out such Id, both UserControl ViewModel will receive it and in that ViewModel, I have no clue on how to differentiate it. (Please correct me if I understand comment wrong).

Comment: you will need one instance of the usercontrol per file. This is for sure. You can simply add an id to the constructor of you viewmodel. That's it. The id will match the id of the message.

Comment: Do you mean, instead of using ViewModelLocator, I should use MainViewModel to create instance for each user control ? (sorry for so many questions, I still in learning phase of this MVVM Light.)

Comment: Nope, in the locator you can tell to create a new instance and not to reuse it. I think it was done by giving a Func<>

Comment: You might find this useful: http://depblog.weblogs.us/2014/02/11/navigating-to-same-viewmodel-but-with-different-data-and-keep-navigation-stack-correct-with-mvvm-light/

Comment: Why don't you create two UCViewModel properties in MainViewModel and interact with these instead of sending messages? If the TabControl will always contain two TabItems, the number isn't dynamic anyway and you know that there will always be two child UCs.

Comment: @Marco, thanks for your suggestion. (but I am a bit far to understand on that one due to my knowledge).

Comment: @Elhamer, thanks for the link provided. That's new and resourceful for me. but as of now, I choose mm8 way of doing thing. It is easier for me though I will lost design time binding naming in intelliense.

Comment: @mm8, thanks for your advice. I chose your way. I found a similar case in codeProject too >> https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/463374/WPF-MVVM-Binding-the-UserControl-DataContext-f

Comment: Hi. You can do it like this: SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IUCViewModel>(() => new UCViewModel()); provided that you use Interfaces IUCViewModel otherwise, UCViewModel

Comment: @Marco, thanks for your sample code, I will study it and will check and apply to current one (assuming I can understand what this line is doing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Method 1 (by using mm8's way)**
 
As per @mm8 suggested, I ends up declaring DataContext for each UserControl usage in my MainViewModel class as Properties.
Example (in MainView xaml):

```
<v:UC Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="10" DataContext="{Binding UC2DC}" />
```

However, in order for me to support my design time XAML intelliense supports, I still use default MVVM Light way of DataContext binding.

Example: In ViewModelLocator,

```
static ViewModelLocator()
{
    ....
    SimpleIoc.Default.Register<MainViewModel>();
    SimpleIoc.Default.Register<UCViewModel>();
    ....
}

public UCViewModel CM
{
    get
    {
        return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<UCViewModel>();
    }
}
```

And in MainViewModel,

```
private UCViewModel _uC2DC;

public UCViewModel UC2DC
{
    get { return _uC2DC; }
    set { Set(ref _uC2DC, value); }
}

private UCViewModel _uC1DC;

public UCViewModel UC1DC
{
    get { return _uC1DC; }
    set { Set(ref _uC1DC, value); }
}
```

And somewhere in my MainViewModel, I need to create new instances and put into these properties. 
When I finish everything, I will delete/comment out User Control default MVVM Light DataContext binding, ViewModelLocator's SimpleIoc Register and GetInstance property,etc and it will change to my MainView databinding. 

I am not so sure does it Ok with MVVM way but as of now, it solves my issue.

**Method 2 (by using Marco's way)**
 
After Marco sample code, I came to know that we can register multiple instances of ViewModel with a key to differentiate them and when calling in property, use that key to pull the correct one. 
Below is the code...

For ViewModelLocator

```
static ViewModelLocator()
{
    ...
    SimpleIoc.Default.Register<MainViewModel>();
    SimpleIoc.Default.Register(() => new UCViewModel(), "1");
    SimpleIoc.Default.Register(() => new UCViewModel(), "2");
    ...
}

public UCViewModel UCVM1
{
    get
    {
        return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<UCViewModel>("1");
    }
}

public UCViewModel UCVM2
{
    get
    {
        return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<UCViewModel>("2");
    }
}
```

And in my MainView XAML

```
<TabControl>
    <TabItem Header="Test 1">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="70"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="70"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <v:UC Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="10" 
                DataContext="{Binding UCVM1,Source={StaticResource Locator}}" />
            ...
            ...
        </Grid>
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem Header="Test 2">
        <Grid Background="AliceBlue">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="70"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="70"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <v:UC Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="10" 
                DataContext="{Binding UCVM2,Source={StaticResource Locator}}" />
            ...
            ...
        </Grid>
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

For this approach, it still the same, for design time, we cannot bind to one default DataContext. May be this is give and take for such cases.

Comment: I don't think this can work. TYou are getting all the time the same instance here ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<UCViewModel>(); Unless you use SimpleIoc.GetInstance<TService>(string key) Method...

Comment: @Marco, in ViewModelLocator, I comment out those register and GetInstance lines when I finish by design layout and from there I use above code. It is working.

Comment: I have updated based on your suggestions by using SimpleIoc way. Thanks. @Marco